# How to cut a selected part from an image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, face-detection, bounding-box

we are dealing with a problem in our main project and we would like you to help us with it. Our project is Portable Face Recognition System. We need to cut out a face from a selected boundary.

This is our code:

```
img=imread('10.jpg'); 
for i = 1:size(img,1) 
    for j = 1:size(img,2) 
        R = img(i,j,1); 
        G = img(i,j,2); 
        B = img(i,j,3); 
        if(R > 92 && G > 40 && B > 20) 
             v = [R,G,B]; 
             if(abs(R-G) > 15 && R > G && R > B) 
                  final_image(i,j) = 1; 
             end 
        end 
    end 
end 
imshow(final_image) 
rgbInputImage=img; 
%Grayscale To Binary. 
binaryImage=im2bw(final_image,0.6); 
%Filling The Holes. 
binaryImage = imfill(binaryImage, 'holes'); 
binaryImage = bwareaopen(binaryImage,1890); 
figure,imshow(binaryImage); 
labeledImage = bwlabel(binaryImage, 8);
```

Comment: this is the code so far we've done...img=imread('10.jpg');
   
for i = 1:size(img,1)
for j = 1:size(img,2)
R = img(i,j,1);
G = img(i,j,2);
B = img(i,j,3);
if(R > 92 && G > 40 && B > 20)
v = [R,G,B];
if(abs(R-G) > 15 && R > G && R > B)
final_image(i,j) = 1;
 end
end
end
 end
 imshow(final_image)
 
rgbInputImage=img;
%Grayscale To Binary.
binaryImage=im2bw(final_image,0.6);
%Filling The Holes.
binaryImage = imfill(binaryImage, 'holes');
binaryImage = bwareaopen(binaryImage,1890);   
figure,imshow(binaryImage);
labeledImage = bwlabel(binaryImage, 8);

Comment: blobMeasurements = regionprops(labeledImage, final_image, 'all');
 numberOfPeople = size(blobMeasurements, 1)
% numberOfPeople =1;
imagesc(rgbInputImage); title('Outlines, from bwboundaries()'); 
%axis square;
hold on;
boundaries = bwboundaries(binaryImage);
for k = 1 : numberOfPeople
thisBoundary = boundaries{k};
plot(thisBoundary(:,2), thisBoundary(:,1), 'g', 'LineWidth', 2);
end
hold off;
imagesc(rgbInputImage);
hold on;
title('Original with bounding boxes');
%fprintf(1,'Blob # x1 x2 y1 y2\n');

Comment: for k = 1 : numberOfPeople 
x1 = thisBlobsBox(1);
y1 = thisBlobsBox(2);
x2 = x1 + thisBlobsBox(3);
y2 = y1 + thisBlobsBox(4);
x = [x1 x2 x2 x1 x1];
y = [y1 y1 y2 y2 y1];
plot(x, y, 'LineWidth', 2);
end

figure, imshow(labeledImage);
B = bwboundaries(binaryImage);
imshow(B);
text(10,10,strcat('\color{green}Objects Found:',num2str(length(B))))
hold on
for k = 1:length(B)
boundary = B{k};
plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'g', 'LineWidth', 0.2)
end

Comment: do not add your code in comments... edit the question instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the MATLAB in-built function [roipoly](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roipoly.html). It will take the `x-y` coordinates of a boundary and build a polygonal mask. This binary mask can be multiplied with your image to extract the face.

Answer (score 0):

You can use imcrop function in MATLAB. for more info type help imcrop in command window.